# Analogue of AUR for gentoo

Tags: gentoo, portage, aur

Is there a portage extension with user installation scripts like the AUR for Archlinux.

I’m curious about Gentoo, and so far every distribution I’ve come across, be it Debian or red hat based, has an extension of the core repositories that lets you occasionally install non free software. I was wondering what would the analogue be for gentoo?

Comment: The "repos" are called [_overlays_](https://overlays.gentoo.org/)... and there's at least one tool to manage them - [`layman`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Layman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one analogue.

Generically, this type of thing is known on portage-based systems (like Gentoo as an 'overlay'.  You can find an example (unofficial overlay) [here](https://github.com/Ferroin/ahferroin7-overlay).  Anybody can create one, you just have to get it onto your system somehow and the configure portage to use it.

As a general rule, managing overlays by hand is nontrivial, especially if you are using more than one.  Luckily, Gentoo provides a tool called `layman` (`app-portage/layman` in the Gentoo portage tree) that can handle this for you.  It allows installation, synchronization, and various other services for overlays on the official list, as well as providing easy configuration of additional lists of overlays that you can install from.

Comment: So basically, it searches all of the overlays in a list for a specific package, but they're not centralised like in Arch. That's neat!

Comment: The really neat bit is that each overlay can have a different priority, so portage can be configured to prefer packages from one over another.

Comment: Ok. So basically the AUR works like a flattened centralised version of all overlays. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called `layman`. It allows for custom repositories, distros based on Gentoo use that, there is even a Steam repository for portage users. Layman use "overlays" which are basically custom portage repositories.
Adding repos adds available packages for `portage`, Gentoo's package manager.

There is more information on Gentoo Wiki: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Layman

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo's Portage supports this with [Custom ebuild repositories](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki//etc/portage/repos.conf#Custom_ebuild_repository).